# Better/Worse/Static in one word?

Tags: single-word-requests

Looking for a word that describes the status of a condition, getting worse or better, or stays the same? Eg "What is the ..... of this condition?"

Comment: The exact context probably makes a difference - but if you were asking about someone's *medical* condition, perhaps ***progress*** might be usable (though if the condition were known to be inherently incurable that might seem a little off).

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use *status*?

Comment: _Status_ isn't specific enough. For example the status of my temperature could be too hot, too cold or just right, whereas the question is specifically about whether it's going up, going down or staying the same.

Comment: .....prognosis.

Answer (score 2):

**Trajectory** is sometimes used to describe the concept of "how a measurable thing is changing", especially in scientific / academic / generally geeky contexts.

This is a metaphorical usage so it's hard to find references for it, but [here's an article from the Economist](http://www.economist.com/news/finance-and-economics/21636089-fears-are-growing-trades-share-worlds-gdp-has-peaked-far) (a well-respected British magazine) that uses it in reference to GDP.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about meteorological conditions, "What is **the forecast** for this condition?" is appropriate.

But if your doubt is about a medical condition, "What is **the prognosis** for this condition?" should be used.

Edit: maybe I misunderstood your question.  Are you looking for "What are the possible variabilities?" or "What's the current situation?

> - variability (noun) "The quality, state, or degree of being variable or changeable."

Comment: Don't both of these refer to _expected future change_, not change that actually took place?

Comment: Both those two refer to the *expected future state* of the condition, but OP seems to be specifically asking about *the current "vector"* (i.e. - for a person with terminal cancer the prognosis is definitely "poor" or worse, but at any given time he might well be going through a period of remission/improvement).

Comment: If it's medical, that would be history, even if the change is current. For weather, record, perhaps. For vibes, What's the mood?

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking about the condition, is whether it changed.

> Has this condition changed?

Now, strictly speaking, this is a yes/no question, and only if you get the answer *no*, you would be sure about one of your three situations.

*However*, these kind of yes/no questions carry an implied question as well. By asking if the condition has changed, you imply this, longer question:

> Has the condition changed, and if so, in what way has it changed?

People will normally understand the implied question, and answer it.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, because you are asking about change, you might use ***evolution***?

> 2 The gradual development of something. - [*Oxford Dictionaries*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/evolution)

Probably though, you might be more likely to say "How is this condition *evolving*?"